# big delay with php CURL execution

Tags: php, curl

I just moved to new hosting and faced issue my php files loads very long - 10s.

I found the exact reason, any CURL php request takes 8-10s to respond.
For example, I need to detect some GEO stuff by IP using curl requests to some 3rd party services ( https://geoip-db.com/json/ , https://api.ipdata.co/ )

[image: loadtime.png]

Here is php code:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.ipdata.co/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$data = curl_exec($ch); // string
curl_close($ch);

echo $data;
?>
```

I tried with SSL and without, tried different websites, all takes 8-10 seconds.
Same php code works perfectly in previous hosting.
Also, when I login to server by SSH and make curl command by command line - it works instantly.

This hosting run same php version as my previous hosting ( 7.2.2).

What could be the reason of issue?

Comment: I had same problem on my old host. I changed curl on "exec('wget -O- .." as temporaly solution. it was solved after update php-curl. 
I'm not sure but I think it had problem with folow location  https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION.html 
Try to change it